# Recalculate stress tensor on a different fault plane

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a stress tensor (3D) and I want to recalculate it on a specific fault plane with strike/dip/rake given.

I have calculated eigenvalues and eigenvectors for a primed tensor and normal and slip vector for a new fault plane.

I found instruction here http://thesis.library.caltech.edu/2060/1/AppendixA.pdf
but I cannot proceed with rotating normal and slip vector by
strike angle in the principal coordinate frame to produce the
eigenvectors.

Can somebody help me? Please!

ok, let's say I have a tensor 
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        6 & 1 & 2 \\
        1 & 5 & 3 \\
        2 & 3 & 4 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$
and I want to calculate it on a fault plane with a strike/dip/rake: 10/30/-95. Normal Cartesian coordinate system with Y axis parralel to the fault.

So as I understand, first I rotate the tensor 350 deg (counter clock wise) about 1-2 plane, to get 10deg strike. Then I rotate it 45 deg about 3-1 plane (using the wabpage you gave me - I have already known it). 
This gives me a tensor 
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        3.36 & -1.55 & 0.81 \\
        -1.55 & 5.37 & 3.12 \\
        0.81 & 3.12 & 6.26 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$
It's symmetrical, ok. When calculating the same transformation in matlab package I found I have identical results.

What about rake then? Does it influence?

When using the package I found and when incorporating a rake into the calculation I get:
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        6.26 & 3.12 & 0.81 \\
        -0.81 & 1.55 & -3.37 \\
        3.12 & 5.37 & -1.55 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$
So this one is asymmetrical, but the values within a tensor are the same.

I don't get it...

Comment: At what point of the process are you stuck?

Comment: I'm at the stage that I have calculated eigenvalues and eigenvectors for a primed tensor and normal and slip vector for a new fault plane. Following the instruction I should somehow rotate the normal and slip vector by strike angle in the principal coordinate frame to produce the eigenvectors.

Can u help me? Or maybe there is another way to do that

Comment: I am not conversant with the terminology you use, so I will use somehow more general terms. To express the stress tensor $\mathbf{\sigma}$ in the new coordinate system , one uses the expression $ \mathbf{\sigma}' = R \cdot \mathbf{\sigma} \cdot R^{T}$. Can you define the rotation matrix $R$ from your fault geometry?  In general you do not need to go through the eigenvalues calculation (which is tantamount to selecting a convenient coordimate system whereby the stress tensor can be written as a diagonal matrix).

Comment: Dear aedonist,
can u look here http://thesis.library.caltech.edu/2060/1/AppendixA.pdf  ?

As I understand I should be able to calculate this rotation matrix as I have normal and slip vectors but I don't know how...

Maybe you would know if u take a look? There is a chapter about this at 10th page

Comment: @zb, I had a look art what you suggested and it is not clear to me whether you want to 1) rotate the stress tensor by a known quantity around a given axis, and then rotate it by un unkown quantity, in order to find the principal stresses on the given plane 2) rotate the stress tensor by two given rotation angles

Comment: @Anaedonist I found some software to calculate normal, shear and Coulomb stress changes on a particular plane (one of the results is the transformed stress tensor), but is it possible to get ASYMMETRICAL one?

Comment: In the second case, you might find the calculator at http://www.continuummechanics.org/stressxforms.html useful. If this is what you are triyng to do, your problem is simply, given two 3D coordinate systems, to find two rotations around two axes to bring the first to the second.

Comment: I would say it is not possible to get an asymmetric matrix rotating a symmetric one. In physical terms,  imagine that the shear stress $\tau_{xy}$ is different from $\tau_{yx}$: then you would not have rotational equilibrium. These arguments are explained in any Continuum Mechanics book. Maybe there is some sign convention I am missing in your specific field. I am taking about classical linear elasticity, not micropolar solids or similar exotic stuff.

Comment: I am not on fb regretfully..just edit your other question with the specifc tensor you rotated and by what rotations, and we will sort it out.

Comment: @Anaedonist I have updated the main issue.

Comment: I am struggling to understand what is going on. Is the software you are using reporting what each matrix entry stand for? I am wondering if there is some bizarre naming convention. Usually the entry $ a_{11}$ stands for $\sigma_{xx}$, the $a_{12}$ stands for $\tau_{xy}$, maybe in geology there are different conventions??